# How to add data manually and from other tables to a table in SQL?

Tags: sql, insert

I need to insert data into a relation table. I want to add three different types of data. Two ints and a string. The table looks like this:

```
drop table if exists Favorite cascade;
create table Favorite (

    id_user int,
    id_serie int,
    since date,
    primary key (id_user, id_serie),
    foreign key (id_user) references User (id_user),
    foreign key (id_serie) references Serie (id_serie)
);
```

Tables `User` and `Serie` have been already created and it's values have been already inserted.

I want to insert into table `Favorite` all the data, making sure Favorite.id_user = User.id_user and also Favorite.id_serie = Serie.id_serie but I also want to add manually the `since` field.

How can I do this?

```
insert into Favorite (id_user, id_serie, since) [What should I type here?];
```

Would something like this work (I guess it won't)?

```
insert into Favorite (id_user, id_serie, since) select User.id_user, Sere.id_serie from User, Serie values ('2020/02/15');
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
INSERT INTO Favorite (id_user, id_serie, since) 
SELECT 
    User.id_user, 
    Serie.id_serie, 
    '2020/02/15' 
FROM User, Serie 
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> Would something like this work (I guess it won't)?

Yes, what you ask will work pretty well.

Is this what you are looking for?

```
INSERT INTO table3 (table1.column1, table1.column2, table2.column3, ...)
SELECT table1.column1, table1.column2, table2.column3, 'constant value' ...
FROM table1, table 2
WHERE condition;
```

Go here for more
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp